# iterate JSON response with jQuery for Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, servlets, highcharts

I made a servlet which creates a Map Object:

```
Map<String, Integer> data = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
```

fills in data and returns a response in JSON format using google JSON:

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(data);
```

All this works fine when retrieving data and iterating them into a table. But I need it in special format for the Highcharts plugin:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Monday',
     data: [10]
    }, {
     name: 'Tuesday',
     data: [20]
  }, {
     name: 'Wednesday',
     data: [30]
    }, {
     name: 'Thursday',
     data: [40]          
    }, {
     name: 'Friday',
     data: [50]
    }, {
     name: 'Saturday',
     data: [60]            
    }, {
     name: 'Sunday',
     data: [70]             
}]
```

In order to achieve this you have to create the script as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            defaultSeriesType: 'column',
            rightMargin: 80
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Weekdays'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: somewhere in a calendar'
        },

         xAxis: {
            labels: {
                enabled: false
        }
        },

        yAxis: [
            {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Amount'
                 }
            },
            {
                linkedTo: 0,
                opposite: true
            }
        ],

         series: []
    };

    $.getJSON('WeekdayServlet', function(data) {

        var series = [];

        $.each(data, function(key, value) {

            series.name = key;
            series.data = value;

        options.series.push(data);
    });

    // Create the chart
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

 });
```

Anyhow, I am doing something wrong here. Either in the iteration or how I "initialize" **series**.

Here are my sources for better understanding:

- http://jsfiddle.net/PPAUx/718/
- http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use (point 3.1 Case study: preprocessing the data)

Comment: mind telling us what the problem is ?

Comment: either series gets filled with the last index of the key/value pair or series can't be shown at all. I need all of them instead. That points out that the push method get's overwritten until last index is shown. Allthough I need it as a speical array form (shown in the series example above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[]` should map to a Java collection such as `List` or an array. The `{}` should map to a `Map` or some Javabean.

So, the desired JSON format can be translated/achieved as follows:

```
public class Serie {
    private String name;
    private Integer[] data;

    public Serie() {
        // Keep default c'tor alive.
    }

    public Serie(String name, Integer... data) {
        this.name = name;
        this.data = data;
    }

    // Add/generate getters/setters/etc.
}
```

and

```
List<Serie> series = new ArrayList<Serie>();
series.add(new Serie("Monday", 10));
series.add(new Serie("Tuesday", 20));
series.add(new Serie("Wednesday", 30));
// ...
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
data.put("series", series);
// ...
String json = new Gson().toJson(data);
// ...
```

Comment: With this approach I don't need to iterate in js code anymore. Instead I could acutually just push "data.series" from JSON response. Logging  those two variables with **console.log** (data & data.series) also shows that it has the correct format. But pushing it to the empty array seems fail anyway. JSON ouput: "series":[{"name":"Monday","data":[10]},{"name":"Tuesday","data":[20]},{"name":"Wednesday","data":[30]}]... pasting this to jsfiddle shows that it should work.

Comment: I have to check my code first, before marking your answer as correct... somethings seems to fail... sorry

Comment: I had also one bug in the javascript code... The chart was created with the options, but data was not loaded. Allthough it was working when I set a breakpoint. So I had to rewrite the script to force the order of the vars being used. thx

Comment: Yes, the `getJSON()` callback runs in a separate thread in the background. You'd like to set the options only in end of callback or when the callback returns.