# Dynamic jSON into Highcharts Pie Chart

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I'm fighting with Highcharts right now trying to get data into it.  If I hard-code the options and series, I can get it to work - so it's not my configuration (i.e. scripts, css, etc.)

I looked at the following question here on SO as it was related: [Ajax JSON in to Highcharts Pie Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646001/ajax-json-in-to-highcharts-pie-chart)

Unfortunately, it didn't help.  Can someone take a look and see what it is that I'm doing wrong?

(This code is directly related to the previously-mentioned SO post)

```
function renderChart(divId, chartType, chartTitle){
    var options = createOption(divId, chartType, chartTitle);
    var series = createSeries();
    options.series = series;    
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
}

function createOption(divId, chartType, chartTitle){
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: divId,
            defaultSeriesType: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: chartTitle
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        series: []
        };
        return options; 
}

function createSeries(){
    var series = [];
    series.push('[');
    series.push('{');
    series.push('"type" : "pie",');
    series.push('"name" : "fruits",');
    series.push('"data" : [');
    series.push('[');
    series.push('"Apple",')
    series.push('43.0');
    series.push('],');
    series.push('[');
    series.push('"Pear",')
    series.push('57.0');
    series.push(']');
    series.push(']');
    series.push('}');
    series.push(']');
    return series.join('');
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Disregard.  Easiest way - have the server cook up the series object.  See this post: [iterate JSON response with jQuery for Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432640/iterate-json-response-with-jquery-for-highcharts)

Comment: Why not dynamically construct an object instead of a JSON string? Does Highcharts require a string of JSON?

Comment: I can create an object as below, but when I'm getting key-value pairs back from the web server, how am I to construct an object dynamically?

series: [{
           name: 'Desktops',
           data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
        }, {
           name: 'Laptops',
           data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
        }, {
           name: 'Servers',
           data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
        }]

Comment: Solved.  See edits above.  Will self-answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Oh, didn't see your last comment

Answer (score 3):

You are feeding Highcharts a string:

```
'[{"type" : "pie","name" : "fruits","data" : [["Apple",43.0],["Pear",57.0]]}]'
```

where it expects an array of configuration object for the series like:

```
[{
    type : "pie",
    name : "fruits",
    data : [["Apple",43.0],["Pear",57.0]]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind chart with JSON data, directly. You just need to set the json property names as highchart standard. 'Y' for value and 'name' for label.

Your JSON should be as like follow:

[ { name: "Apple", y: 25 }, { name: "Pear", y: 20 } ]