# Use HTML Textbox value as a HighCharts Percentage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, highcharts

I have the following code:

**HTML Code**

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 1,//null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 12.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                },
                            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

The output of this code is a Pie Chart with a value of Chrome(15),IE(31) and Firefox(53) inside of a div.

Here is the set of Textboxes and a button:

```
    Number of Arson: <input type="text" id="arson" name="arson">
    Number of Homicide: <input type="text" id="homicide" name="homicide">
    Number of Physical Injuries: <input type="text" id="physicalinjuries" name="physicalinjuries">
    Number of Carnapping: <input type="text" id="carnapping" name="carnapping">
    Number of Ethical Law Violation: <input type="text" id="elv" name="elv">
<input type="submit" id = "chart" value="Submit">
```

Is it possible to pass the value of textbox and use it as a custom percentage(slices) in a chart(PIE) when the button is clicked?

My goal here is call a PHP Function that will use this select (count) from tablename and pass  it to the textbox then when the button is pressed that value will be sent to the PIE Chart.

Comment: Yes! It is possible :)

Comment: Thank you for that wonderful answer, How? :)

Comment: Just kidding :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775385/how-to-set-dynamic-data-in-highcharts/11786087#11786087

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#chart').on('click', function() {

   var value = Number($('#arson').val());

   var myChart = $('#container').highcharts();

   myChart.series[0].data[0].update(value); 

});
```

Comment: Can you please explain this to me deeper? Just example one textbox. If its ok with you

Comment: Honestly i dont how to try it

Comment: Thank you sir, I will wait Thank you so much

Comment: Ok, I added comments and swapped pieces out with your tags so it makes more sense.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3es9gzxy/ sir i try it take a look at it seems something wrong

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking at your jsfiddle to see what's wrong. I know my code works cause I just used it for myself, but it's not liking any Javascript after yours...let me see.

Comment: Yes sir I just paste it after the code for the chart but when i try  it the pie chart doesnt show

Comment: Try the code now...it will work. I forgot to turn the value from the input into a number.

Comment: What happen to your code sir? Does it something to do with the function? Something Conflict?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3es9gzxy/2/ Sir take a look at my updated jsfiddle the chart is showing but when i put the value in the textbox arson and press the button submit the value from the pie chart doesnt change but the chart shows

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work on jsfiddle, but the code works, because I tested it in my text editor and in my browser with no problems. As to why it doesn't work on jsfiddle...not sure.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3es9gzxy/4/ this is the latest code its working but. like for example if i input 22% on the value of arson it doesnt look the same as the value in the pie chart

Comment: That's because of how highchart's pies work. Those values you initially had set are not the percents, but just numbers, but the pies automatically calculate the % depending on the numbers inputted. So if you wanted Firefox to be 50%, the number inputted needs to be 50% of the total. Firefox: 10, Chrome: 5, IE: 5 results in Firefox 50%. You can probably change the settings for the pie to use the inputted number as percent.

Comment: My last line about changing settings doesn't make sense because the numbers inputted will act as the percent, as long as the total for all the slices add to 100, if they don't...highcharts calculates the percent for you.