# Highcharts Pie Chart data corrupted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, charts, highcharts

I have a `Highcharts` pie chart which uses an `Ajax` call to retrieve data in the for of a `JSONArray`. I need to strip the data of all ("") and make it a `Javascript` object but I am running into difficulty. `JSON.Parse()` throws an error because it is saying that the data is already parsed.

How do I get this data in the correct format for a pie chart?

**Call**

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({ 
        url: '/data/pie_chart.jsp', 
        cache: true,
        datatype: 'json',
        error: function () { },
        success: function (data, status, rsp) {
            alert(data);
            setPieData(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**Data**

```
[{"name":"Dual","load":"20"},{"name":"Gas","load":"35"},{"name":"Other_Fossil_Fuels","load":"15"},{"name":"Nuclear","load":"12"},{"name":"Hydro","load":"8"},{"name":"Wind","load":"10"},{"name":"Other_Renewables","load":"10"}]
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7432462/3281415) answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your json should return string for name and number of y. however the workaround is to parse string to number as following

```
 var dataPie =[];
var abc =[{"name":"Dual","load":"20"},{"name":"Gas","load":"35"}, 
{"name":"Other_Fossil_Fuels","load":"15"},
{"name":"Nuclear","load":"12"},{"name":"Hydro","load":"8"},{"name":"Wind","load":"10"},
{"name":"Other_Renewables","load":"10"}];

$.each(abc,function(i,el)
{
  dataPie.push({name :el.name,y: parseFloat(el.load)});

});
```

See the [Working fiddle with your json](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/ng1kvmxh/)

Comment: Better is using parseFloat()

Comment: Agree with @SebastianBochan , must use parseFloat()